# When I hit https://<external IP>, I want to be able to access the application running on port 3000 on the container in GEC

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nuxt.js

I wrote Dockerfile like this and I push it to Container Registory on GCP

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python make g++
COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app
RUN rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000
ARG API_ENDPOINT
ENV API_ENDPOINT $API_ENDPOINT

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

[image]

I deployed docekr image on gce instance. I can access application using http://:3000. But What I finally want to do is to access application using https://. I don't know what to do for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a simple way of running a container and send HTTPS requests to it, you can deploy on Cloud Run instead of GCE. Your problem is that you are just running an HTTP server and for HTTPS you need to add at least a certificate and matching DNS-name for your server. Cloud Run is a higher abstraction level service that will do that for you. Obviously you can get it done in many ways using GCE as well, but it will be more involved.

You can use gcloud to deploy your container if you already have it in the registry. Here is an example:

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/CONTAINER-ID --platform managed --port 3000
```

You can get your project id by running `gcloud config get-value project`

Here is the full quickstart for Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy

Comment: thank you nice advice. I execute `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/CONTAINER-ID --platform managed --port 3000` and I got url. I accessed application url. this error was shown. `Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.`

Comment: maybe run.services.setIamPolicy is insufficient. I'll search it.

Comment: Add  --allow-unauthenticated to your deploy command. Cloud Run containers only allow authenticated requests by default.